# Kubernetes - Helm not upgrading cron job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-cronjob, kubernetes-jobs

I have deployed many things with Helm into my Kubernetes cluster. My values.yaml file contains a lot of fields.

The only modification I want to perform is add an additional environment variable to my cron job. (This cron job creates a pod where a python script should be able to read this environment variable)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
...
...
    containers:
        - env:
            - name: existing_env_var
              value: "dummy_value"
            - name: new_env_var                # I want to add this one
              value: "this is the new one"
```

The update must be done keeping the old unmodified values. The command:
`helm upgrade [name] [path] --reuse-values`

The problem is that cron job is not upgraded, meaning my python script can not use the new env variable. Only reason I can think of that no changes were made in the context of helm because none of the values were modified.

How could I upgrade my CronJob while reusing the old values. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got to do with the definition of the `--reuse-values` flag. As per the documentation [here](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/):

```
--reuse-values : when upgrading, reuse the last release's values and merge in any overrides from the command line via --set and -f
```

Trying overrides directly from within the chart while using `--reuse-values` would not work. Pass the new value (which is the only value you want to add to this chart) via --set or -f.

This will presumably mean you will have to tweak your chart a bit to pass the environment variables to your cron job via values file.

This [article](https://medium.com/@kcatstack/understand-helm-upgrade-flags-reset-values-reuse-values-6e58ac8f127e) explains its usage very well.